# Unable to upload any sketch but Serial Monitor keeps displaying "Start scan, Scan done, Network found" message

Tags: arduino-mega, uploading

I have bought a new Mega 2560 with WiFi.

I tried to upload a sketch that worked OK with the previous Mega 2560 but the upload always fails with the following error message:

```
*************************************************************
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

Sketch uses 2762 bytes (1%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.

Global variables use 391 bytes (4%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7801 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.

C:\Users\warph\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -CC:\Users\warph\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cwiring -PCOM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\warph\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_593938/2560-Mega-WiFi.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\warph\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM3

         Using Programmer              : wiring

         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Can someone please help to get this issue fixed?

Comment: Did you select the correct COM port?

Comment: remove the tx rx pin and try again

Comment: you have esp8266 on USB. use the DIP switches to configure the board https://robotdyn.com/mega-wifi-r3-atmega2560-esp8266-flash-32mb-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

Comment: My apologies for the dumb question but did you try to upload any other, simpler, sketch on this Mega board?

Comment: Thanks a lot. All good after changing the DIP switch settings.